# Proof by induction, binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I have to make the following proof:
$${\sum\limits_{k=1}^n}{k}{n\choose k} = n2^{n-1}$$

Base case, $n = 1$:

$${\sum\limits_{k=1}^{1}}{k}{1\choose k} = 1 = 1\cdot2^0=1$$
Inductive Hypothesis:

for int $p = n$
$${\sum\limits_{k=1}^p}{k}{p\choose k} = p2^{p-1}$$

Inductive Step; here is where I am having some trouble.... Can I get any hints to where I can take this?
$${\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p+1}}{k}{{p+1}\choose k} = p2^{p}$$
Expansion:

$${{p+1}\choose 1} + \cdots + {p}{{p+1}\choose p} + (p+1){{p+1}\choose {p+1}} $$

Comment: One can use the Pascal Identity $\binom{p+1}{k}=\binom{p}{k}+\binom{p}{k-1}$.

Comment: Oh right!That works

Comment: The suggestion was for an induction proof. There are better non-induction proofs.

Comment: Differentiate $(1+x)^{n}$ and then replace $x$ by $1$ to find sum of coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$(1+x)^n=1+C_{n}^{1}x+C_{n}^{2}x^2+\cdots+C_{n}^{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$$
Differentiate both sides in terms of $x$
$$n(1+x)^{n-1}=C_{n}^{1}+2C_{n}^{2}x+3C_{n}^{3}x^2+\cdots+(n-1)C_{n}^{n-1}x^{n-2}+nx^{n-1}$$
And let $x=1$.

Comment: I like this proof, but it does not answer the question of the OP: to complete the induction.

Comment: Yeah I know that, But as for the induction proof @André Nicolas has answered it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Basic  non-inductive proof:

For $k\ge1,$
$$k\cdot\binom nk=k\cdot\frac{n!}{n!\cdot k!}=k\cdot\frac{n\cdot(n-1)!}{\{(n-1)-(k-1)\}!\cdot k\cdot(k-1)!}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

$$\implies S=\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom nk=\sum_{k=1}^nn\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

Set $k-1=r$  $$\implies S=n\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}r=n(1+1)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another non-inductive proof:

If
$s
=\sum\limits_{k=1}^p{k}{p\choose k}
$,
then
$s
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^p{k}{p\choose k}
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^p(p-k){p\choose p-k}
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^p(p-k){p\choose k}
$
so
$2s
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^p{k}{p\choose k}
+\sum\limits_{k=0}^p(p-k){p\choose k}
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^p(k+(p-k)){p\choose k}
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^p p{p\choose k}
=p\sum\limits_{k=0}^p {p\choose k}
=p2^p
$.